# Android tab used as button

Tags: java, android, google-maps, tabs

I want one of my tabs in my `TabLayout` to essentially work as a `Button` where when pressed the default calculator is opened instead of a tab with an `Activity` in it. How would I go about doing this? Below is know it would be done with a `Button`.

```
Button calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalcButton);
calcButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent calcIntent = new Intent();
            calcIntent.setClassName("com.android.calculator2",
                    "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
            startActivity(calcIntent);
        }
    });
```

edit: I want the calculator to open full screen not within the tab view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a onTabChangeListener and when ever the user goes to that tab, you could just launch the intent you want to start.

```
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    if(TAB_BUTTON_TAG.equals(tabId)) // TAB_BUTTON_TAG is the tag associated with your tab
    {
        Intent calcIntent = new Intent();
        calcIntent.setClassName("com.android.calculator2", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
        startActivity(calcIntent);

    }

}});
```

Comment: Worked great, I have a new tool in my arsenal. Thank you!